# How can I declare types properly to be able to create groups of redux action creators with shared name parts using createAction?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to use template literal types to create typed groups of Redux actions like "FETCH/START", "FETCH/PENDING", etc.

I want to use @reduxjs/toolkit `createAction` to make my action creators, like this:

```
import { createAction, ActionCreatorWithoutPayload, ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface IFluxAction<T extends string, P> {
  Started: ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload<P, `${T}/START`>;
  Pending: ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<`${T}/PENDING`>;
}

const createAsyncActions = <P>() => <T extends string>(type: T):
  IFluxAction<T, P> => {
    return {

// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'P'.
// 'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which
// could be unrelated to 'undefined'.

      Started: createAction<P, `${typeof type}/START`>(`${type}/START`),
      Pending: createAction(`${type}/PENDING`),
    };
};

enum DocActions {
  Fetch = 'Fetch',
  Delete = 'Delete',
};

export const documentActions = {
  Fetch: createAsyncActions<number>()(DocActions.Fetch),
};

const a = documentActions.Fetch.Started(1);
```

REPL: https://replit.com/@AlexanderBausk/VibrantOffbeatChapters#src/main.ts

I cannot call createAction properly when I need it to return an action creator with payload of type P. createAction is conditionally typed and I just can't seem to get it right. I'm not sure if this is related to me trying to use template literal types, or just improperly structuring my typing.

Would appreciate any help or ideas on how to achieve typed groups of action creators in a better way.

Comment: Try to remove explicit return type. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/wOzqlW). Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

My first answer is **don't try to generate actions like this yourself**.  Instead, use [the `createAsyncThunk` API in Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) to handle creating and dispatching actions related to async requests.  That should eliminate almost all the code you've got here.